# Profiling a legacy application

Tags: profiling, legacy-code

I am using an old version of a metastorm workflow designer.

We support this while we rewriting it in Microsoft Technologies.

After a few changes the "MAP" (*.epc) has become exceedingly slow to work with and "PUBLISH".

The publish writes the map and its binaries to the DB which then a service will pick up and execute.

However the publish "hangs" never completing and taking from a completion time of 15 min to in excess of 3 hours but still not completing.

I can see the CPU is being hammered but memory seems fine.

I ran process monitor but it does not show me much which leads me to believe the process is doing something either than the norm or the map has grown to a point which is leading it to destruction.

My question: How else can I profile this black box exe?

Comment: This might be better answered on http://superuser.com/ rather than here.